# ASP.NET MVC 5 Routing issue using PagedList package

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) package to create a paging section for my tables.
Everything is working fine, but my urls are shown as:

```
http://localhost:55808/suppliers?page=2&sortOrder=id_desc&searchFilter=s
```

So I created a custom route for this using the following code:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        // Index Suppliers with paging / search filter / orderby
        routes.MapRoute(
            "SupplierPaging",
            "suppliers/{searchFilter}/{sortOrder}/{page}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Suppliers",
                action = "Index",
                sortOrder = UrlParameter.Optional,
                searchFilter = UrlParameter.Optional,
                page = 1
            }
        );

        // Default route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Also this is working for the `Index` of my `Suppliers` controller.
Now if I go to the `http://localhost:55808/suppliers/edit/1` page to edit a supplier, it goes into the `Index` method of my controller instead of the `Edit`.

Do I need to add all these methods as custom routes to get it working? Eg:

- A custom route for edit
- A custom route for delete
- ...

Or what am I missing here?

Comment: Yes you need to add custom routes for your edit/delete methods. Since searchFilter and sortOrder are optional, it thinks the id parameter you are passing in is the page #. So something like `suppliers/edit/{id}`

Comment: So there is no easier way to do this? Even if you have for example 20 controllers that uses this package you need to add for each controller and each method of that controller a custom route?

Answer (score 0):

Add route constraints so the first route will not match for other actions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultPaging",
    "{controller}/{searchFilter}/{sortOrder}/{page}",
    new
    {
        action = "Index",
        sortOrder = UrlParameter.Optional,
        searchFilter = UrlParameter.Optional,
        page = 1
    },
    new
    {
        sortOrder = @"\d+",
        searchFilter = @"\d+",
        page = @"\d+"
    }
);
```

Also I've replaced "suppliers" part of the route with "{controller}", so this will work for all controllers with paging.